# RGB Color equivalent in ubuntu terminal prefences menu

Tags: command-line

What is the equivallent of RGB color in the Ubuntu terminal preferences menu?

The code is something like #F3532525 and i have a RGB color code that i want to set as my default color in my terminal. How can i do that?

Comment: no its not. I mean in the preferences where the code its like #F252352.

Comment: I reedited my question maybe its clearer now what i am trying to do.

Comment: I see, you can easily convert RGB to color code with any graphic application, or a simple tool like `gcolor2`. e.g. pure red is rgb: `255,0,0`, or `#FF0000`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the police and default colors throw the preference panel (edit-preference)

(assuming you are talking about windows terminal like xfce4-terminal or xterm)

Comment: Yes i am aware of that but the format there is not RGB. I have the code of the RGB color but i dont understand the format in the preference panel